# Use wtoi with radix in c++

Tags: c++, c-strings, converters, wchar

I need to convert a hex value stored in a wchar_t c-style string to an int. the atoi function has the parameter radix for this, but the wtoi only takes a wchar_t. Is there a function(usable for c++, much c functions are deprecated in c++) or another way to achieve this?;

Comment: Besides the C-function [`std::wcstol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcstol) there's also [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). Both of these should be easy to find out about with a little searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) is overloaded on both `std::string` and [`std::wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and takes an optional base parameter.  You can construct a `std::wstring` form a `wchar_t` c-style string.